# Set the gap for Gurobi.Optimizer in Julia-JuMP

Tags: gurobi, julia-jump

I am trying to understand how to set the gap for Gurobi.Optimizer, because it solves too long when the default gap threshold is used (10e-4).
I couldn't find it anywhere (they might be referred to as attributes or parameters).

PS: Also, I am trying to find the right tutorial or instructions on how to use the solver in JuMP. I checked here https://juliahub.com/docs/Gurobi/do9v6/0.7.7, but they don't reveal the meanings of different attributes and inputs. Please, send me one in case somebody knows.

Best,
A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the MIP gap via the [MIPGap](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/mipgap2.html) parameter:

```
using JuMP, Gurobi

model = Model(Gurobi.Optimizer)
set_optimizer_attribute(model, "MIPGap", 0.1)
```

You can read more about JuMP here: https://github.com/jump-dev/Gurobi.jl